# Git FileRevision get comment with multiple lines - gets only first line

Tags: java, eclipse, git, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I am working on Eclipse plugin. I try to extract all source code revisions (from git repo or svn or any other repository) with information: commit id, date, author, message.

And I have a problem with commit messages, those with multiple lines. **TL;DR I am getting only first line from commit messages that has multiple lines.** Any ideas how to get whole mesage contents?

Below is a working code. Just put in first line the name of the project from your workspace that has connected SCM.

```
    IProject selectedProject = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("testGit");
    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(selectedProject);
    IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();

    for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
        if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
            for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
                IResource file = unit.getResource();
                IFileRevision[] revisions = getFileRevisions(javaProject, file);
                if (revisions != null && revisions.length > 0) {
                    for (IFileRevision revision : revisions) {
                        System.out.println(revision.getComment());
                        System.out.println("============================================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private IFileRevision[] getFileRevisions(IJavaProject project, IResource file) {
    RepositoryProvider repositoryProvider = RepositoryProvider.getProvider(project.getProject());
    IFileRevision[] revisions = null;
    IFileHistoryProvider fileHistoryProvider = repositoryProvider.getFileHistoryProvider();
    if (fileHistoryProvider == null)
        return null;
    IFileHistory iFileHistory = fileHistoryProvider.getFileHistoryFor(file,
            FileHistoryProvider.SINGLE_LINE_OF_DESCENT, null);
    if (iFileHistory != null) {
        revisions = iFileHistory.getFileRevisions();
    }
    return revisions;
}
```

Please note that you need to **create new Plug-in Project**, not Java Project. Then it is needed to add **dependencies** and then fix missing imports:

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.team.core,
 org.eclipse.team.ui
```

Code may be run anywhere. The simpliest way is to create Hello World plugin and run the code somewhere in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that *EGit* class `CommitFileRevision` only returns a short message, see [source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/tree/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/internal/storage/CommitFileRevision.java?id=02d111faf8563675d7983de013f6e7f9c0b2f664#n92).

In order to get the full comment, I - by no means being an expert - believe you have to use *JGit*, specifically [`RevCommit.getFullMessage()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/3.5.1.201410131835-r/org.eclipse.jgit/apidocs/index.html). Maybe you want to look into the [JGit user guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#RevCommit) for more info. There are also a few questions here on SO concerning this topic, please search for yourself.

---

**Update:**

Here is a quick & dirty code snippet fetching the `RevCommit` from the (non-public, but package-local) *EGit* class `CommitFileRevision` via reflection. I put the code inside the "Hello world" plugin's menu action:

```java
public void run(IAction action) {
    //MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(), "SO_GitPlugin", "Hello, Eclipse world");
    try {
        IProject selectedProject = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("SoccerTable");
        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(selectedProject);
        IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();

        for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
            if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
                for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
                    IResource file = unit.getResource();
                    IFileRevision[] revisions = getFileRevisions(javaProject, file);
                    if (revisions != null && revisions.length > 0) {
                        for (IFileRevision revision : revisions) {
                            Method method = revision.getClass().getMethod("getRevCommit");
                            method.setAccessible(true);
                            RevCommit revCommit = (RevCommit) method.invoke(revision);
                            System.out.println(revision);
                            //System.out.println(revision.getComment());
                            System.out.println(revCommit.getFullMessage());
                            System.out.println("============================================");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Don't do this at home, kids! ;-) It is just a hacky proof of concept without actually having to bootstrap everything with *JGit*. And BTW, you have to add the plugin dependency `org.eclipse.jgit` to your project.